# Typescript map.get method returns undefined when my key is of some interface type

Tags: typescript, dictionary

I have a main.ts file which is having a map with key as interface `dr` and value as string. when i try to get some value from the map using `get` it returns undefined .Below is my code:

```
interface dr {
a: string;
b: string;
}

let myMap = new Map<dr,string>();
myMap.set({ a: 'foo', b: 'bar' }, `this is my map`);

export default (a:string,b:string): string => {
return myMap.get({ a: a, b: b })!;

};
```

Comment: You try to get it using a *different object* that happens to have the same data in it. Since the check is done using object equality, that means the two aren't equal as they aren't literally *the same* object.

Comment: Don't use objects as keys, if you're not using the same reference, you're going to be getting undefined.

Comment: But my key is supposed to be a pair of strings.Any other way to do this ?

Comment: `\`${a}|${b}\`` for example

Comment: @VLAZ i didn't get it.Please could you explicitly write that ?

Comment: Just create your key as a string that is a combination of two strings. Use some sort of delimiter between the two, ideally, a value that will not show up. So, if you want to create a key from `a = "foo"` and `b = "bar"` you can have `"foo|bar"` as the compound key.

Comment: @VLAZ indeed, that is a good way to go here, but he could just use an object at that point. Anyway perhaps support for custom comparisons will be added someday but hopefully TC39 will see the folly of their _maximally minimal_ aspiration one day.

Comment: @AluanHaddad the [record proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-record-tuple) (which also includes tuples) is already in play. It's to create immutable "objects" (records) and immutable "arrays" (tuples) that can be safely checked by value and thus serve as keys in maps among other things.

Comment: Yes, I've read through that proposal. I think there's potential, and it would be nice to have them as keys, and it would certainly be appropriate for this question's use case, and still be nice to be able to customize lookups on a map instance, especially for libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object equality is different to primitive values, because objects are not compared using their property values, but if they have the same reference.

```
let myMap = new Map<dr,string>();
myMap.set({ a: 'foo', b: 'bar' }, `this is my map`);
```

Here you set `{ a: 'foo', b: 'bar' }` in your map, but you don't store the reference anywhere, so you will never be able to `get` it back from the map.

Instead you'd have to do:

```
var a = { a: 'foo', b: 'bar' };
myMap.set(a, `this is my map`);
myMap.get(a) // returns 'this is my map'
```

Alternatively, you could "stringify" your object, so instead of storing values with objects as keys, you store them with a string:

```
var a = { a: 'foo', b: 'bar' };
myMap.set(`${a.a}${a.b}`, `this is my map`);
myMap.get('foobar') // returns 'this is my map'
```